# Installing and running browserquest on ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpserver

I have installed node.js and necessary packages to run [browserquest](https://github.com/mozilla/BrowserQuest). I have started the browserquest server, which is running on port 8080 and when I go to my browser and type http://localhost:8080/status I can see that server is running and currently no clients are connected. I build the client with configurations like this in client/config/build_config.json file

```
{
   "host": "http://127.0.0.1",
   "port": 8080
}
```

I build my client within bin/build.sh. Then I run this command to create http-server to serve client files.

```
http-server path-to-client-build -p 8000
```

I can see the index page with the httpserver running by going to http://localhost:8000/index.html but when I try to connect it gets stuck after saying connecting to server.

NOTE: I am using this http-server to host client files http://search.npmjs.org/#/http-server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the client-build has some problems on the current release on github. Instead I have used the actual client folder. I have followed these steps to make it work.

Make sure you have installed node and npm.

1) get a copy from github repo.

```
git clone https://github.com/mozilla/BrowserQuest.git
```

2) Install the required node packages for the server

```
npm install underscore log bison websocket websocket-server sanitizer memcache
```

3) Start the server

```
node server/js/main.js
```

4) go to the client directory and install http-server module to serve the client files

```
cd client
npm install -g http-server
```

5) edit config_build.json-dist to point to your host ip and port (in my case 127.0.0.1 localhost)

```
{
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"port": 8000,
"dispatcher": false
}
```

6) copy the edited config_build.json-dist to 2 new files

```
cp config_build.json-dist config_build.json
cp config_build.json-dist config_local.json
```

7) copy shared folder into client folder

```
cp -r ../shared .
```

8) start the http-server to serve the client files

```
http-server
```

And your server and client should be running. You can check if the server is running by going to http://ipaddress:port/status which should display an array of connected clients. If none an empty array. And your client should be running on http://ipaddress:8000/index.html

based on the tutorial from dirkk0
https://gist.github.com/2275361

Comment: Thx for the mention!
I updated a gist with an even more condensed version:
https://gist.github.com/3604699